# Homology of product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am suppsosed to compute singular homology of $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{D}^2-\{(1,0)\}$, namely $H_*(X;\mathbb Z)$ for my space $X$, but I don't even have an idea of which tools to use.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you considering $S^1\times (D^2\setminus\{(1,0)\})$? Otherwise removing the point $(1,0)$ from $S^1\times D^2$ doesn't makes sense to me.

Comment: Moreover, if this is the case $D^2$ is the open disc so $(1,0)$ doesn't lie in $D^2$. Please clarify your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the point $(1,0)$ from $S^1\times D^2$ doesn't make much sense to me unless further explanation is provided by the OP in terms of notation. I assume that the space in question is:
$$
S^1\times (D^2\setminus\{(1,0)\})
$$
even though in this case $D^2$ is the open disc and $(1,0)$ doesn't belong in $D^2$!! So it might be that $D^2$ denotes the closed 2-disk. The OP doesn't clarify.

---

In any case $D^2\setminus\{(1,0)\}$ is contractible hence $S^1\times (D^2\setminus\{(1,0)\})
$ has the same homology groups as $S^1\times \{pt\}$ i.e. the same homology groups as $S^1$.

---

$H_0=\mathbb{Z}$ since $S^1$ is path-connected and $H_1=\mathbb{Z}$ since  $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian.
$H_k=0$ for $k\geq 2$ since $S^1$ is a one-dimensional manifold.

---

If the OP meant that from $S^1\times D^2$ we remove $\{(p,q)\}$ with $p\in S^1$ and $q\in D^2$ then $S^1\times D^2 \setminus \{(p,q)\}$ is the interior of the 2-torus with a point removed, which is contractible i.e. has the homology of a point.

Comment: Removing $(1,0)$ from $S^1\times D^2$ makes sense. The sphere has $e^0=1$ and the disk has an origin.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I agree but then notation shouldn't be different and explicit? I wanted mostly to point out the need to be explicit.

Comment: I meant the second case. But thanks for your advices anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention was $S^1 \times (D^2 - \{(1,0)\})$, then the following works:

$D^2 - \{1,0\}$ is contractible, so it is enough to consider $S^1$. In this case, one $H_1= \mathbb Z$. One can think about it as just "Fattening up $S^1$ (minus a line). $H_n$ is trivial for all $n>1$.

Let $f:(D^2-\{(1,0)\}) \times [0,1]$ be defined by $\mathbf{x} \mapsto (1-t) \mathbf{x}$ for all $\mathbf{x},t \in (D^2-\{(1,0)\}) \times [0,1]$. This defines a retraction onto $\mathbf{0}$.

Note that it matters that the point missing is $(1,0)$, since otherwise there would be an "obstruction" in the straight line contraction to the origin.

Comment: But, isn't $\mathbb S^1$x{$0$} $-$ $(1,0)$ just $\mathbb S^1$ $-$ $1$? And how can I get that in that case $H_n$ is trivial..

Comment: Do you know that Homology is homotopy-invariant?

Comment: Okay, I get it. And what about $H_0$, is it isomorphic to $Z$ since there is only one path component to consider?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Eurydice please see the edits. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Removing $(1,0)$ from $S^1\times D^2$ makes sense. The sphere has $e^0=1$ and the disk has an origin.

Comment: Thanks, even though I meant the first case. :) I am just confused, how to prove that punctured disk is contractible..

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Why does the fact that $\mathbb D^2$ is contractible, imply that removing a point preserves a homotopy between my first space and $\mathbb  S^1$x{$0$}$-$$(1,0)$